# electron have 2 types?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, mocha.js

can somebody know how to update version of electron because when i run mycode in npm start is working but when i run my code in mocha test is have a lot of error electron

[image: the image]
the left one is run with : npm start

the right one isrun with : test mocha

and the problem is i think the electron is different version

can somebody explained what happened :)

this is my package json

this is my packagejson

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.13",
    "@ugenu.io/electrolizer": "^1.0.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "electron": "^9.4.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "mocha": "^8.3.2",
    "nightmare": "^3.0.2",
    "nightmare-upload": "^0.1.1"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `"electron": "^9.4.3"` to like `"electron": "^12.0.0",`